# How to pass context parameter to Query parameters value in Talend

Tags: talend, query-string

In Talend studio, i am creating a job which involves supplying URL and query parameters to 'tRest_Client' component and facing below stated issue -

I am trying to pass context parameter data to Query parameter value as below

**Context parameter -**

```
Name : mis_id
Default : 10
```

**Query Paramaters -**

```
name : "query"
value : {target-rel[=context.mis_id]}
```

**actual URL -** 
    URL+query={target-rel[=10]}

Here i am trying to pass value 10 with 'context.mis_id'

When i run the talend job, no data is passed to the Value of Query Parameter.

Please let me know if this is correct way to pass Context parameter data.

Comment: Which component ? please explain the job and add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to include the context variable in a query parameter, then try remember how Java works with a static string and a variable, since talend is a Java based tool.

Say in Java, I have a variable,

```
String world = "World!!!";
System.out.Println("Hello "+world); // This will display as Hello World!!!
```

Likewise, in talend you have to use as

`"{target-rel[="+context.mis_id+"]}"`

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: Well explained. Thank you

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, you can accept this as the best answer. For clarification on this, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers